# How do I test the front-end on a series of webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I wanted to know:

1. Softwares that can do this.
2. Technology needed to do this.
3. Any particular languages that would make this easier.

Edit: Answered the question with some tools etc that would help anyone else looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ghost inspector
https://ghostinspector.com/

I think this can handle your requirement

it has option to build tests with google chrome plugin with which you can do the steps once and then it can repeat the same automatically and has several more features